# Unable to make routing with my bootstrap nav bar using ngroute

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have benn trying ngroute with simple examples but unable to get desired result., I tried routing in Nav bar like below

```
<li>
                <a href="#Components">
                    <i class="fa fa-recycle"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text">Reusable Components</span>
                    <span class="selected"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

and another horizontal nav bar like this

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#/home">Plan</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#/about">Test</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="menu2">Track</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="menu3">Organise</a></li>
            </ul>
```

for these i created a routing.js file like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.test = 'Hello World';
});

app.controller('pageCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.test = 'Some page';
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/Views/home', {
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
 })
    .when('/Views/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
 .when('/Views/Components', {
    templateUrl: 'components.html',
    controller: 'pageCtrl'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/index'
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

but unable to get routing done... can any one help me.

Comment: Have you tried `href="/Views/Components"`? Note that if you're using html5mode then you also need to specify a base in your index: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="home">Plan</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="about">Test</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="menu2">Track</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="menu3">Organise</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

can you checkout this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lHOsNpgAbJ2ahiyXE4ok?p=preview

Comment: :- When i am hovering on those links I am getting localhost:7777/index.html#/home and its not routing to new page., am i missing any thing